# Hangouts API: Is "Room Name" exposed anywhere in API?

Tags: google-apps-script, hangouts-api

I've read the documentation at https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces/get

and I've successfully retrieved "memberships" information in JSON format using spaces.get. However, I'm not seeing anywhere I can get the room name - for example, I'd like to ideally be able to automatically log the corresponding room name that my bot is added to for the purposes of an internal process my organization uses.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Is the `displayName` from the [response](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/spaces#Space) corresponds to the Room Name? You will need to indicate the type of a space - **ROOM**.

Comment: @jess you're totally right, how did I miss that? How do I accept your answer?

Comment: I will post this as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the displayName from the response corresponds to the Room Name? You will need to indicate the type of a space - ROOM.